# Why is counter cache not being utilized after I increase the size?

Tags: cassandra, database-performance, cassandra-3.0

My Cassandra application entails primarily counter writes and reads.  As such, having a counter cache is important to performance.  I increased the counter cache size in cassandra.yaml from 1000 to 3500 and did a cassandra service restart.  The results were not what I expected.  Disk use went way up, throughput went way down and it appears the counter cache is not being utilized at all based on what I'm seeing in nodetool info (see below).  It's been almost two hours now and performance is still very bad.

I saw this same pattern yesterday when I increased the counter cache from 0 to 1000.  It went quite awhile without using the counter cache at all and then for some reason it started using it.  My question is whether there is something I need to do to activate counter cache utilization?

Here are my settings in cassandra.yaml for the counter cache:

```
counter_cache_size_in_mb: 3500
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
counter_cache_keys_to_save: (currently left unset)
```

Here's what I get out of nodetool info after about 90 minutes:

```
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: false
Load                   : 1.64 TiB
Generation No          : 1559914322
Uptime (seconds)       : 6869
Heap Memory (MB)       : 15796.00 / 20480.00
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 1265.64
Data Center            : WDC07
Rack                   : R10
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 1345871, size 1.79 GiB, capacity 1.95 GiB, 67936405 hits, 83407954 requests, 0.815 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 5294462, size 778.34 MiB, capacity 3.42 GiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 24064, size 1.47 GiB, capacity 1.47 GiB, 65602315 misses, 83689310 requests, 0.216 recent hit rate, 3968.677 microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 8.561186035383143%
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
```

Here's a nodetool info on the Counter Cache prior to increasing the size:

```
Counter Cache          : entries 6802239, size 1000 MiB, capacity 1000 MiB,
                         57154988 hits, 435820358 requests, 0.131 recent hit rate,
                         7200 save period in seconds
```

Update:
I've been running for several days now trying various values of the counter cache size on various nodes.  It is consistent that the counter cache isn't enabled until it reaches capacity.  That's just how it works as far as I can tell.  If anybody knows a way to enable the cache before it is full let me know.  I'm setting it very high because it seems optimal but that means that the cache is down for several hours while it fills up and while it's down my disks are absolutely maxed out with read requests...

Another update:
Further running shows that occasionally the counter cache does kick in before it fills up.  I really don't know why that is.  I don't see a pattern yet.  I would love to know the criteria for when this does and does not work.

One last update:
While the counter cache is filling up native transport is disabled for the node as well.  Setting the counter to 3.5 GB I'm now going 24 hours with the node in this low performance state with native transport disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a way to 100% of the time avoid the counter cache not being enabled and native transport mode disabled.  This approach avoids the serious performance problems I encountered waiting for the counter cache to enable (sometimes for hours in my case since I want a large counter cache):
1. Prior to starting Cassandra, set cassandra.yaml file field counter_cache_size_in_mb to 0
2. After starting cassandra and getting it up and running use node tool commands to set the cache sizes:
Example command:
nodetool setcachecapacity 2000 0 1000

In this example, the first value of 2000 sets the key cache size, the second value of 0 is the row cache size and the third value of 1000 is the counter cache size.

3. Take measurements and decide if those are the optimal values.  If not, you can repeat step two without restarting Cassandra with new values as needed

Further details:
Some things that don't work:
Setting the counter_cache_size_in_mb value if the counter cache is not yet enabled.  This is the case where you started Cassandra with a non-zero value in counter_cache_size_in_mb in Cassandra.yaml and you have not yet reached that size threshold.  If you do this, the counter cache will never enabled.  Just don't do this.  I would call this a defect but it is the way things currently work.
Testing that I did:
I tested this on five separate nodes multiple times with multiple values.  Both initially when Cassandra is just coming up and after some period of time.  This method I have described worked in every case.  I guess I should have saved some screenshots of nodetool info to show results.

One last thing:  If Cassandra developers are watching could they please consider tweaking the code so that this workaround isn't necessary?